# Local isometry of complete length spaces that is not a covering map

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Let $\pi:\widetilde{M}\to M$ be a surjective local isometry between complete length spaces (local isometry means that every point $x\in \widetilde{M}$ has a neighborhood which is isometrically mapped to an open neighborhood of $\pi(x)$). It is a covering map if $M$ is locally convex (i.e. every point has a neighborhood in which every two points are connected by the unique geodesic). Can we drop the last condition? (Or else I'd like a counterexample.)

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the fact that you stated?

Comment: This condition is not needed, just check the path lifting property for rectifiable paths, this will suffice for the covering property.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz https://people.math.ethz.ch/~lang/LengthSpaces.pdf or https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257947117_The_Hadamard-Cartan_theorem_in_locally_convex_metric_spaces

Comment: @Misha but the unique path lifting alone does not imply covering property (by covering I mean locally trivial bundle with discrete fibers), doesn’t it? Something like local simply-connectedness is required normally.

Comment: Oh, you a right, of course; the proof that I know requires existence of a simply-connected covering space. I guess, you are interested in spaces which do not have such covers, right?

Comment: @Misha yes, the counterexample necessarily won’t have a simplyconnected cover. Maybe some local isometry to Hawaiian earring will do the job, but I cannot come up with an example